# In reinforcement learning, after an action, the state does not change

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

After conducting an action, the state of the agent may change into a new state, also may not change. So is it still reasonable to formulate the problem by MDP and solved it by reinforcement learning problem?

Answer (score 1):

The transition function is allowed to send a state back to itself with non-zero probability, so this is perfectly fine for an MDP.